# How do I calculate conditional variance for a discrete problem?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

**Problem:**

> A manuscript is sent to a typing firm consisting of typists A,B, and
> C. If it is typed by A, then the number of errors made is a Poisson
> random variable with mean 2.6; if typed by B, then the number of
> errors is a Poisson random variable with mean 3; and if typed by C,
> then it is a Poisson random variable with mean
> 3.4. Let X denote the number of errors in the typed manuscript. Assume that each typist is equally likely to do the work.

**Attempt:**

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&X \mid A \sim \operatorname{POI}(2.6) \\
&X \mid B \sim \operatorname{POI}(3) \\
&X \mid C \sim \operatorname{POI}(3.4)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
P(A)=P(B)=P(C)
\end{equation}

I first calculate the expectation of $X$.

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
E(x) &=E(X \mid A) \cdot P(A)+E(X \mid B) \cdot P(B)+E(X \mid C) \cdot P(C) \\
&=2.6 \cdot 1 / 3+3 \cdot 1 / 3+3.4 \cdot 1 / 3 \\
&=1 / 3(2.6+3+3.4) \\
&=3
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

I know that the formula for conditional variance is:

\begin{equation}
\operatorname{Var}(X)=E(\operatorname{Var}(X \mid Y))+\operatorname{Var}(E[X \mid Y])
\end{equation}

But I don't understand how to incorporate all the discrete events. My guess is to apply this formula for all the probabilities conditioned on $A,B,C$ and then take the (weighted) average, but this attempt is more based on a guess than sound mathematical thinking.

Could I please get feedback on this?

Comment: I would use $E[X^2] = (E[X])^2 + Var(X)$  which you can easily find for each typist and so for the mixture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used the Law of Total Expectation and the definition of expectation to evaluate: $$\begin{align}\mathsf E(X)&=\mathsf E(\mathsf E(X\mid Y))\\&=\big(\mathsf E(X\mid A)+\mathsf E(X\mid B)+\mathsf E(X\mid C)\big)/3\end{align}$$

So, just do the same.  Well, add the definition of variance where needed.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(\mathsf{Var}(X\mid Y)) &= \big(\mathsf{Var}(X\mid A)+\mathsf{Var}(X\mid B)+\mathsf{Var}(X\mid C)\big)/3\\[3ex]\mathsf{Var}(\mathsf E(X\mid Y))&=\mathsf E(\mathsf E(X\mid Y)^2)-\mathsf E(\mathsf E(X\mid Y))^2\\[1ex]&=\big(\mathsf E(X\mid A)^2+\mathsf E(X\mid B)^2+\mathsf E(X\mid C)^2\big)/3-\mathsf E(X)^2\end{align}$$